# Hide date_select tag rails 5 using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks

I'm trying to hide a date select tag in rails 5 on document ready with jQuery, the tag looks like this:

```
<%= date_select :search_input, params[:search_input], class:"form-control mr-sm-2 " ,id:"date_select"%>
```

and the jQuery code:

```
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function
  $("#date_select").hide();
})
```

This similar idea works when hiding another tag, but it doesnt work with the `date_select_tag`. Any sugestions please?